# change user PrincipalName necessary

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, userprincipal

If I change/patch the mail with Graph api should I also change the userPrincipalName with the corresponding new e-mail convetions?
Or is this not necessary?

The change is made by specifying the new email address in the "mail" field, as in the following example:

perl

```
{ 
  "mail": "003SpesenTest@chri.com" 
}
```

It is important to note that only the user's email address is changed. However, it is unclear whether the UserPrincipalName (UPN) also needs to be changed. The UPN is usually composed of the email address and the domain name. This UPN is used for logon, while within Active Directory (AD) the mailNickname is always used. The mailNickname corresponds to a mail alias that does not include "@", etc. Here is an example:

Is it now necessary to change all data

```
mailNickname = 008SpesenTest_chri.com#EXT#
userPrincipalName = 008SpesenTest_chri.com#EXT#@xx.onmicrosoft.com
mail = 008SpesenTest@chri.com
```

to be changed to the

```
mailNickname = 003ExpenseTest_chri.com#EXT#
    userPrincipalName = 003SpesenTest_chri.com#EXT#@xx.onmicrosoft.com
    mail = 003SpesenTest@chri.com
```

or is it enough to change only the mail? Can the guest user log in to the teant with the new email if userPrincipalName still has the old email reference?

thx for your helps and infos

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.